# Is it possible to get the sendBeacon HTTP result?

Tags: javascript, sendbeacon

I am sending data using `sendBeacon`. Every time I send a beacon, I also  know that the user's login session was extended, so I also update a timestamp in a `sessionStorage` key whenever I send a beacon to the current time.

But, sometimes a user returns after the session ends, and then the POST code from the `sendBeacon` is 419, yet the timestamp still updates but that affects other scripts that rely on that `sessionStorage` timestamp

Is there any way to then get the HTTP code from the POST of the `sendBeacon` and update the timestamp only if it succeeded? the return values for `sendBeacon` are only true/false if it successfully sent it, but nothing to do with the result itself.

But maybe there is still a way to get the HTTP result in a different way? I know I can change that to `fetch` or AJAX, but I am specifically using `sendBeacon` for analytics as described in the docs so I thought it's the best use case for it here

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon: _"Note: For use cases that need the ability to send requests with methods other than POST, or to change any request properties, **or that need access to the server response**, instead use the fetch() method with keepalive set to true."_